# Import scss file is not working inside storybook file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, storybook

I'm currently facing issue on storybook react using **scss**. I'm using **sb init** to create the storybook file. Everything is working, all the addons loaded but only the style is not working. If I use `css` file, the style will be working.

I'm already following the instruction from documentation on using `@storybook/preset-scss` and the `webpackFinal` config, but it still not working

this is a sample from storybook file

**import './button.scss';** is not working properly

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import './button.scss'; -> this one not working

export const Button = ({ primary, backgroundColor, size, label, ...props }) => {
  const mode = primary ? 'storybook-button--primary' : 'storybook-button--secondary';
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={['storybook-button', `storybook-button--${size}`, mode].join(' ')}
      style={backgroundColor && { backgroundColor }}
      {...props}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};

Button.propTypes = {
  primary: PropTypes.bool,
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(['small', 'medium', 'large']),
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  backgroundColor: null,
  primary: false,
  size: 'medium',
  onClick: undefined,
};
```

this is my `/storybook/main.js` file

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-scss"
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base')

const config = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    library: 'violets'
  }
}

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, config)
```

`webpack.base.js`

```
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin(),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ],
  },
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {
          compact: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        sideEffects: true,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { importLoaders: 1 }
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve('sass-loader')
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [
                /*  eslint global-require: ["off"]  */
                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                autoprefixer({
                  flexbox: 'no-2009'
                })
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom'
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'violets.min.css'
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I encountered similar problem and the following Github thread fixed for me:

[storybookIssue-12464](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12464)

Here is the summary (ensure that you have scss installed ):

1. In my case, I did not have preset-scss addon installed. I did it by using:

   `npm install @storybook/preset-scss --save`

In you case it seems like preset-scss addon is already present.

2. Commenting out config rules in `main.js` file:

   `config.module.rules.push({`

   `test: /\.scss$/,`

   `use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],`

   `include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),`
   `});`
3. If this doesn't work, try importing your scss file in `preview.js` of storybook config folder.

   `.storybook > preview.js > import your CSS file;`

Finally, some reference which might be useful for you:
[SCSS-Presets](https://github.com/storybookjs/presets/tree/master/packages/preset-scss)

Comment: Follow storybookIssue-12464 solve my issue. I just install @storybook/preset-scss --save. and add the following addon: '@storybook/preset-scss',

Answer (score 4):

If you have the storybook version "^6.5.0" you can do the following:

1. If you don't have the `sass` package installed, just run:

```bash
yarn add sass
```

2. Use a storybook addon for scss
   Install the addon by running

```bash
yarn add @storybook/preset-scss -D
```

3. Then add the following addon to your list of used addons `'@storybook/preset-scss'` on the *`.storybook\main.js`* file.

You'll see more about it on https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12464#issuecomment-730196791.

Answer (score 0):

For webpack 4, downgrade the versions to,

```
yarn add -D @storybook/preset-scss css-loader@5.2.6 sass sass-loader@10.1.1 style-loader@2.0.0
```

Add preset-scss in addons of .storybook/main.js

```
"@storybook/preset-scss"
```

This worked for me